# Chain custom GRPC client interceptors/DialOptions

Tags: go, grpc, middleware, grpc-go

I want to chain some `DialOptions`/client-side interceptors. But for some reason only the latest of my custom interceptors will be invoked:

```golang
myOpt1 := grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
    print("testInterceptor invoked")
    return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
})
myOpt2 := grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
    print("testInterceptor2 invoked")
    return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
})
opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        myOpt1, // will be skipped
        myOpt2, // will get invoked
}

conn, err := grpc.DialContext(context.Background(), "my-adress:443", opts...) // err is nil
myService := pbAugment.NewMyServiceClient(conn)
myService.MyFunction(context.Background()) // prints: testInterceptor2 invoked
```

I've added `TransportCredentials` so I don't get an error on startup (about missing transport security).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must chain (Client|Server) interceptors:

See [`grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.60.1#WithChainUnaryInterceptor)

E.g.:

```golang
func main() {
    myInt1 := func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
        print("testInterceptor invoked")
        return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
    }
    myInt2 := func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
        print("testInterceptor2 invoked")
        return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
    }
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor(
            myInt1,
            myInt2,
        ),
    }

    _, err := grpc.DialContext(context.Background(), "my-adress:443", opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now there's a difference between `DialOptions` and `Interceptors`. So while there're mutliple `DialOptions` allowed, only a single one can specify the `Interceptors`, is that right? I somehow thought that `WithTransportCredentials` would returned an `Interceptor`, too, and wondered why I couldn't find it's interception logic - but now it makes sense!

Comment: You're welcome. Here's the struct for [`dialOptions`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/dbbcf59957fec0bd58063224cbf105b3b3698d4e/dialoptions.go#L54). It contains a single ``unaryInt`` (whcih you were effectively `apply`'ing mutliple times and getting the most recent only) and a slice of `chainUnaryInts` (which is what you're now correctly `apply`'ing your interceptors to). For streaming interceptors, there's a parallel set of fields (`streamInt`, `chainStreamInts`)

Comment: Yeah, I glanced at this code multiple times when I tried to understand what's happening, but somehow I didn't manage to see the bigger picture. It feels so obvious in hindsight! Thanks again! :)

Comment: I agree it's not obvious until you've seen it used. Good luck!